# Vue Video Background does not start

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm starting as a frontend developer with VueJs and I'm having a problem that I can't understand... So I hope if some could help me... I'm currently using [avidofood
/
vue-responsive-video-background-player](https://github.com/avidofood/vue-responsive-video-background-player)

Because I need some kind of video playlist in the background. I implemented such as official documentation said (at least I think so..) but nothing happened, I mean, I have no errors, but the video does not start. This is my code:

> In App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="App">
    <video-background
      src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpAxlizirDI"
      style="max-height: 80%; height: 100vh"
    >
      <h1 style="color: white">Test App!</h1>
    </video-background>

    <div class="container mt-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-10">
          <div class="form-group barcode">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <input
                  id="barcode"
                  type="text"
                  name="barcode"
                  class="form-control pl-3 shadow-none bg-transparent border-0"
                  placeholder="Acerca el producto al lector..."
                  autofocus
                  onfocus="this.value=''"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
//Oculto el mouse
//document.body.style.cursor = "none";

export default {
  name: "App",
};
</script>

<style>
#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.text-color {
  color: rgb(212, 14, 14) !important;
}

.barcode {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 45px;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

> In main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.esm';
import App from './App.vue'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';

import VideoBackground from "vue-responsive-video-background-player";
Vue.component("video-background", VideoBackground);
   
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
   
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#App')
```

> In Vue dev Tool:

[image]

> In Chrome Console:

[image]

> This is de Project Structure:

[image]

I hope someone could help me because I have no little idea what's going on.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: it does not support youtube as of now... you can check to their github page

Comment: Yes, Thanks... but i changed it to 
` <video-background src="assets/demo_producto.mp4" style="max-height: 80%; height: 100vh" > ` But does not work either...

Answer (score 0):

As source, you have a YouTube page, this is not a video.

```
 <video-background
  src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpAxlizirDI"
  style="max-height: 80%; height: 100vh"
>
```

> This is your path to your video. You can just use this value for
> showing your video in every resolution.

The source of the video has to be in a format the browser can play (mp4 is a good format to use).

For example:

```
  <video-background
    src="/files/my-video.mp4"
    style="max-height: 80%; height: 100vh">
```

---

Update based on your comment:

Because vue gets compiled it does not know what `assets/demo.mp4` is,. You should import it first via an loader.

```
<script>
  import video from 'assets/demo.mp4' // Or '@/assets/demo.mp4' depending on what loader you use.
  
  export default {
    name: "App",
  };
</script>
```

And now you could use:

```
  <video-background
    :src=video
    style="max-height: 80%; height: 100vh">
```

Comment: I thought that and made something like this:

`
  <video-background
      src="assets/demo_producto.mp4"
      style="max-height: 80%; height: 100vh"
    >
`
But does not work either...  Should be in public folder?

Comment: are you using vue-responsive-video-background-player@1.2.1?

Comment: yes...   "vue-responsive-video-background-player": "^1.2.1"

Comment: mmm.. ok that's make sense... but now i have dependency problem with this new import:

This dependency was not found:
`
* assets/demo.mp4 in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& `